# How can I forward old access logs to a new syslog destination (redhat)?

Tags: syslog

I just setup a syslog forwarder but how do I forward older historical logs (like access_log)? Is it possible to replay log files so they'll send historical entries?

Comment: Why not just copy them over with scp/rsync/etc?

Answer (score 1):

The logger command has a '-f' option that allows you to specify a file name. '-n' lets you specify a remote server to send it to.

Comment: On my RHEL6 systems, `logger` does not support the `-n` flag.

Answer (score 1):

You can stream any text file to syslog via `logger`. This will follow whatever streaming method you've specified in `syslog.conf`, so make sure that your syslog.conf file lists the syslog server before you do this.

```
cat access_log | logger -t access_log_old
```

This will take access_log, read it line by line, and simply send the entire line to your syslog server with the tag of 'access_log_old'. Some caveats:

- Each line will includes the date field at the beginning of access_log, which may not be what you want. You can use `sed` or `awk` to strip the date field from each line. Something like this would work:

  ```
  cat access_log | sed 's/MATCH//g' | logger -t access_log
  ```
- Note that the event time in syslog will be the time that the event was received, not the event in the log.